# Programmatically setting viewbox child

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a load of vector images which I have mocked up in inkscape and then imported into my project as canvases within resource dictionaries. When designing my form I show them like this:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="MyViewbox"
         Width="400" 
         Height="150" 
         Child="{StaticResource Image1}"/>
```

I would now like to programmatically change the shown image. So far I have:

```
Dim img As New Uri("Images/Image2.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
Dim bmpimg As New BitmapImage(img)
ElectrodeImage.Child = bmpimg
```

I get an error on the final line saying it is not possible to convert a BitmapImage to a UIElement. What is the correct way to do this? Alternatively, I am open to using an imagebox instead of a viewbox, but I am also unsure how to proceed there.

Comment: Besides that BitmapImage is not a vector image, you can not create a BitmapImage from a XAML file. Use XamlReader.Parse instead.

Comment: As @Clemens says, I cannot load a vector image into a bitmap.  I think a solution using XamlReader.Load is possible, but I would need to determine the path to the xaml file. My solution was to do the following: `ElectrodeImage.Child = ElectrodeImage.FindResource("Image2")`.